# Compile python to cython (local variable 'webdriver' referenced before assignment)

Tags: python, selenium, cython

I'm compiling python to cython in mac os and get this error

```
warning: tag.py:404:4: Unreachable code

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
             print(event)
     window.close()
     print('logging to account')
     sleep(randint(2, 3))
     chromedriver_path = './chromedriver'
     webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path)
                ^
------------------------------------------------------------

tag.py:153:17: local variable 'webdriver' referenced before assignment
```

I think the error belongs to these lines

```
chromedriver_path = './chromedriver'
webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path)
webdriver.minimize_window()
```

Comment: The assignment to `webdriver` makes that name a local variable within whatever function contains this code - which means that the name *doesn't* refer to the Selenium module that you imported earlier.  Use a different name for the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method `minimize_window()` in Selenim Python bindings :

remove that .

Instead I think you wanna maximize :

```
driver.maximize_window()
```

Do not assign `webdriver` to a `webdriver`

do this instead :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
```

**Imports  :**

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

Comment: there is a method minimize_window() and I'm using it and minimize the window and tried with driver stuff and still the same

Comment: well I do not see `minimize_window()` in webdriver API - here is the official link https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html - Why would even that be needed ? why would one wants to minimize it window for UI automation  ?

Comment: I don't know if there is or not but its working on my script and because I have a custom debug window and want to follow the debug window its just for testing mode

Comment: I think that would be a wrapper around to any functions, but I can assure you there is no such method developed by Selenium devs. I have been working with Selenium for more than 5 years now.. I am pretty much sure. Anyway did it resolve the above error  ?

Comment: suddenly it worked with the driver thing.... but if I use [driver = webdriver] and in the rest of the code I use like [webdriver.get('https://www.example.com')] it gonna be a problem?

Comment: yes there will be errors since, webdriver is an interface.. and moreover it's a reserved by Selenium, try to use driver.ger("some URL")

Comment: so i must change all webdrivers to driver right?